# Proper use of semicolons in functions and procedures

Tags: sql, postgresql

I don't know where to put the semicolons in the following structure. I've tried writing the semicolons after both 'with as' as per my interpretation of the docs but that's not right:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_product(product_name VARCHAR, category_name VARCHAR)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    as $$
    BEGIN
      WITH ins_category AS(
        INSERT INTO product_category(name) 
        VALUES(category_name)
        ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING
        RETURNING id
        )
      WITH ins_product AS(
        INSERT INTO product(name, product_category) 
        SELECT product_name, ins_category.id FROM ins_category
        RETURNING sku
        )
      COMMIT;
    END;
    $$
```

This works but I'm starting to think I've just added extra semicolons for no good reason:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_product(product_name VARCHAR, category_name VARCHAR)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN
  WITH ins_category AS(
    INSERT INTO product_category(name) 
    VALUES(category_name)
    ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING
    RETURNING id
    )
  INSERT INTO product(name, product_category)
  SELECT product_name, ins_category.id FROM ins_category; //DO I NEED THE SEMICOLON HERE
  COMMIT;
END;
$$
```

In the first example I need the second 'with as' because I would like to continue the procedure and insert another row to another related table.

A. My questions where and why do I need to add semicolons in the first example?

B. Do I have extra semicolons in the second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second table needs to be preceded by a comma not a semi-colon.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_product(product_name VARCHAR, category_name VARCHAR)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN
  WITH ins_category AS(
    INSERT INTO product_category(name) 
    VALUES(category_name)
    ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING
    RETURNING id
    ),
  ins_product AS(
    INSERT INTO product(name, product_category) 
  SELECT product_name, ins_category.id FROM ins_category
    RETURNING sku
    )
      <SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE>

  COMMIT;
END;
$$
```

Comment: Why is a comma needed between two 'with as'?

Comment: I've tried adding a comma after the first 'with as' but I'm still getting a syntax error. this time after COMMIT;

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the second WITH isn't needed, just a comma before the next table.

Comment: No it gives an error as I've said this time it's after the COMMIT

Comment: Are you not missing your <SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE> after the WITH clause?  The WITH cannot stand on its own.

Comment: I've copy pasted your answer, and when I try to save the procedure it still reports a syntax error

Comment: I adjusted my answer to include my suggestion as to why you are still getting a syntax error.

Comment: Oh I see your new edit. But I'm already inserting with the select no? why do I need another insert before the commit? I mean what should I insert there? am I suppose to always finish with an insert so the last command in the chain would be an insert with no 'AS'?

Comment: It's just the syntax of the language just as Laurenz Albe's answer shows.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for CTEs is:

```
WITH <name> AS (
   <SELECT or INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE ... RETURNING>
) [,
<name2> AS (
   <SELECT or INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE ... RETURNING>
) [, ...] ]
<SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE>
```

So the CTEs need be separated by comma, as stated in HereGoes's answer. It is just part of the syntax.

Semicolons separate different SQL statements, so it is *always* a syntax error to write a semicolon inside an SQL statement (except in a string literal or a comment).

The only possible way to add an extra semicolon is to have two semicolons right next to each other, as in

```
SELECT 42;;
```

Between these two semicolons is an “empty” SQL statement.

Comment: I've removed the second 'with' keyword and added a comma between the CTES , but now I get a syntax error next to the COMMIT

Comment: That is because you ar lacking a semicolon to separate the `INSERT` statement with the CTEs and the `COMMIT` statement.